# Keep growing values in list and hold list size

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Few days ago I have been trying many ways and methods for at get desired behaviour of list in Python. I need to construct a method, which assigns and changes values in list at the same time it keeps size of list. let me explain

***I have such a code.***

```
A = [1,1,1,1,1]
B=[]

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    for j in range(1,3):
        val = j*2*A[i]
        B.insert(i,val)
    print(B)
```

***The result I get:***

```
[4, 2]
[4, 4, 2, 2]
[4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

What I want to do!

take the first value of A-list in this case `int 1`. then make some calculation by increasing a range function. `val = 1*2*A[0] = 2` and set in the B-list, and continue `val = 2*2*A[0] = 4` and set in B-list. then next `val = 1*2*A[1] = 2` and `val = 2*2*A[1] = 4`. I am expecting to have a output like this.

```
[2]
[4]
[2,2]
[4,4]
...............
```

**Update:**

I have updated a sample of code, this time a for-loop is added for construction of `list A` but it runs into some problem.which I do not really understand why it does run with ***error*** `list index out of range.` That is clear, when `len(list A)` is `4`, `len(list B)` becomes `5`. it is not expected `list B` gets out of range?

```
A = []
B = [] 
for n in range(1,11):
    A.append(n/n)
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        B.insert(i, A[i])
        for j in range(1,3):
            for k, _ in enumerate(B):
                B[k] = j*2*A[k]
                print(B)
```

**Output I get:**

```
[2.0]
[4.0]
[2.0, 4.0]       #<------- Not need it 
[2.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 2.0]       #<------- Not need it 
[4.0, 4.0]
[2.0, 1.0, 4.0]  #<------- Not need it 
[2.0, 2.0, 4.0]  #<------- Not need it 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Expected output.**

```
[2.0]
[4.0]
[2.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 4.0]
---------------
```

I do not really know how to solve this type of problem, I appreciate any help...

Comment: Why is "the result I get" an image? Nothing in your code suggests it is creating an image. (This also goes for your previous question where you did the same weird thing. Why ever include text as an image of text? What is that clear advantage that I seem to be missing?)

Comment: What do you mean? should I add that as text not as image?

Comment: :-) yes, you should. It's an uncurable disease here on SO, that people post code or data as images. And I have to admit I also do not get the advantage... The problem is, that from longterm users perspective, this feels sometimes as "they'll never learn, why do they do it over and over again!" - but _"they"_ are different people every time, who learn, but others will do the same.....However, what is as well not understandable: this result is _not_ the result of the code above. So if I run the code, I do not get this result (neither as image, nor as text... :-))

Comment: Obviously That is true. I have fixed and corrected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put the `insert`function in the outer loop, otherwise you insert not only for every element in `A`, but also for every calculation step in `range(1, 3)`

i.e.

```
A = [1,1,1,1,1]
B=[]

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    B.insert(i, A[i])
    for j in range(1,3):
        B[i] = j*2*A[i]
    print(B)
```

or better Python:

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
B = []

for i, elmnt in enumerate(A):
    B.insert(i, elmnt)
    for j in range(1, 3):
        B[i] = j * 2 * elmnt
    print(B)
```

But why do yo want to write `val = 1*2*A[0] = 2` into B[0] if you overwrite it anyway in the next step by `val = 2*2*A[0] = 4`?
That doesn't make sense.

---

EDIT:
Latest agreement about what should be the expected behaviour:

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
B = []

for i, elmnt in enumerate(A):
    B.insert(i, elmnt)
    for j in range(1, 3):
        for k, _ in enumerate(B):
            B[k] = j * 2 * elmnt
        print(B)
[2]
[4]
[2, 2]
[4, 4]
[2, 2, 2]
[4, 4, 4]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[4, 4, 4, 4]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

...or with numpy it's easier to change all values of an array at once:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'int')
B = np.array([], 'int')

for i, elmnt in enumerate(A):
    B = np.append(B, elmnt)
    for j in range(1, 3):
        B[:] = j * 2 * elmnt
        print(B)

[2]
[4]
[2 2]
[4 4]
[2 2 2]
[4 4 4]
[2 2 2 2]
[4 4 4 4]
[2 2 2 2 2]
[4 4 4 4 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. well regarding your question why `val = 1*2*A[0] = 2`, because there are some other conditional statement beneath those line of code, which it is not shown here, it will take `[2]` and check it if the condition is matched, then it will break and get out of for-loop, if the condition is not met, continues overwriting to `val = 2*2*A[0] = 4`

Comment: Very well organized constructed. yet still not getting the desired behaviour. when runs, gets following,`[2], [4], [**4**,2], [4,4]`, desired to get a value for third result as `[2,2]`, is it a way to come around this? I think it take from previous run,

Comment: Hmm, I think there is still some misunderstanding... Yes, it's from the previous run, but this run is finished and so it's data remains untouched. And this  is _not_ wanted... I have to admit I do not understand.

Comment: Your constructed method is usefull and great, one last piece is missing. I think it can be we need one more range function and for-loop.

Comment: So let's think about it step by step: in case of the first element in A (and so in B) j will become first 1 and then 2. That means, the element will be first 2 and then 4. But then, as far as I understand, the next element is processed, and B now has two elements: first [4, 2] and then [4, 4]. Then the third: first [4, 4, 2] and then [4, 4, 4].......... Why should the "finished 4s" change back to 2?

Comment: Ok, however, I still don't get what you want to achieve, so I can't imagine what you might need additionally here.

Comment: You are right and it goes as you explain above. when i becomes 1, B is constructed like this `B[1,1]`, j will become first 1 and then 2, here is the point, when j becomes 1 and 2, i is still 1, that means `B[1] = ........`, i.e. result `B = [unchanged, changed due to i = 1]`, what about first value in B when you have `B = [1,1]` we do not change anything in first value, it is why I say we need one more for-loop and range, because in case `B = [1,1]` changes should be added to `B[0]` and `B[1]` and since `i = 1`, no change occurs for `B[0]` just takes previous value.

Comment: we can take it over chat if you like.

Comment: So _all elements up to the current one_ should be canged in every iteration? First the first one, next the first two, next the first three - always treated the same?

Comment: see my edit. If I may speak honestly: now this is complete nonsense in my opinion. For what do you use the loops then? They are obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for your and reply and solution. I understand you may think, it is nonsense. I want also to be honest. Indeed it is't so much nonsense, as it seems. Think of rebars in concrete beam. Usually you have a series of rebars in one layer. In them there are some tension. think list A as section of rebars and B list of tension, and range function as external load on them, they should get similar portion of forces, and tension changes equally in them when load increases.